# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

```js
Resource.java
  
  @RequestMapping(value = "/updateDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('" + ROLE_BPM_EAUTH_WF_CLIENT + "')")
    public ResponseEntity<UpdateStatus> updateDetails(@RequestBody updateRequest updateRequest) throws ServiceException {
        UpdateStatus response = null;
        try{
             response = controlService.updateDetails(updateRequest);
        }catch (ControlServiceException controlServiceException) {
            if(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE.FAILED_TO_UPDATE_DETAILS.getCode().equals(controlServiceException.getErrorCode())
                    || ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE.FAILED_TO_UPDATE_DETAILS_STALE_DATA_ISSUE.getCode().equals(controlServiceException.getErrorCode())) {
                    final int maxRetryCount = controlService.getMaxRetryCountFromConfig(); 
                    response = retryUpdateDetails(updateRequest, 1, maxRetryCount);
            } else{
                throw controlServiceException;
                }
            }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
 
Service.java
 
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { ServiceException.class })
public UpdateStatus updateDetails(UpdateRequest updateRequest) throws ServiceException {
 Object object = updateRequest.getObject();
 updateDetailActions(updateRequest);
 return InformationTransformer.transformStatus(object, true);

}
 
private void updateDetailActions(updateRequest updateRequest) throws ServiceException {
 DefaultDetails defaultDetails = null;
 if (updateRequest.getEventType().equals(EventTypeEnum.A.getValue())) {
  updateStatusToA(updateRequest);
 }
 Object object = updateRequest.getObject();
 
 ObjectDetail localObjectDetail = objectDetailRepo.getObjectDetailsByCriteria(object);
 ObjectDetail objectDetail = objectCreateHelper.createOrReplaceObjectDetails(updateRequest, localObjectDetail, object);
 EventTypeEnum eventType = EventTypeEnum.getByName(updateRequest.getEventType());
 Boolean isUpdateBSRequired = objectCreateHelper.isRESTCallRequired(updateRequest, localObjectDetail);
 
 if(isUpdateBSRequired){
  defaultDetails = objectCreateHelper.setBSDetails(objectDetail,object);
 }
 performEventRelatedUpdates(updateRequest, objectDetail, eventType);
     
 try {
    populateObjectCriticalityForEvents(updateRequest ,object, objectDetail);
 } catch (ControlServiceException e) {
  throw new ControlServiceException(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE.FAILED_TO_POPULATE_CRITICALITY, e);
 } finally {
  objectDetail = saveObjectDetails(objectDetail, object);
  if(isUpdateBSRequired){
   objectCreateHelper.updateBS(object, defaultDetails);
   if(objectCreateHelper.isPUEnabled(object)){
    performPU(object, objectDetail);
   }
  }
 }
}
 
@Override
public ObjectDetail saveDetails(ObjectDetail objectDetail, Object object) throws ControlServiceException {
 try {
  return objectDetailRepo.saveDetail(objectDetail);
 } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException exception){
    throw new ControlServiceException(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE.FAILED_TO_UPDATE_DETAILS_STALE_DATA_ISSUE, exception);
 }  catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new ControlServiceException(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE.FAILED_TO_UPDATE_DETAILS, ex);
 }
}
```

```css
exception logs :


 Exception occurred while saving Object as org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:43)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282.saveekDetail(Unknown Source)
  at com.ek.acp.service.ekcontrol.impl.ekControlServiceImpl.saveekDetails(ekControlServiceImpl.java:1184)
  at com.ek.acp.service.ekcontrol.impl.ekControlServiceImpl.updateekDetailActions(ekControlServiceImpl.java:331)
  at com.ek.acp.service.ekcontrol.impl.ekControlServiceImpl.updateekDetails(ekControlServiceImpl.java:276)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor764.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
  at com.ek.egsframework.persistence.serviceinterceptors.EGSTransactionInterceptor.executeService(EGSTransactionInterceptor.java:125)
  at com.ek.egsframework.persistence.serviceinterceptors.EGSTransactionInterceptor.transactionWithoutEGSServiceMethod(EGSTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor155.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
  at com.ek.egsframework.persistence.serviceinterceptors.ModuleManagerInterceptor.checkEGServiceAnnotation(ModuleManagerInterceptor.java:65)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy348.updateekDetails(Unknown Source)
  at com.ek.acp.controller.events.ekEventResource.updateekDetails(ekEventResource.java:108)
  at com.ek.acp.controller.events.ekEventResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c1e0a006.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:68)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654)
  at com.ek.acp.controller.events.ekEventResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7109e94.updateekDetails(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at com.ek.web.filter.RequestMDCLogger.doFilter(RequestMDCLogger.java:39)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:242)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:118)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at com.ek.authentication.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:188)
  at com.ek.authentication.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doAuthenticate(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:104)
  at com.ek.authentication.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:72)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at com.ek.security.ping.EGSPingAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(EGSPingAuthenticationFilter.java:114)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at com.ek.web.filter.PingRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(PingRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
  at org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:466)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)

  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:656)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor440.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy196.flush(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor440.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.flush(Unknown Source)
  at com.ek.egsframework.persistence.repository.AbstractJPARepository.flush(AbstractJPARepository.java:120)
  at com.ek.egsframework.persistence.repository.AbstractJPARepository.makePersistent(AbstractJPARepository.java:79)
  at com.ek.acp.repository.ekcontrol.impl.ekDetailRepoImpl.saveekDetail(ekDetailRepoImpl.java:86)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor763.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
  ... 151 more
```

```html
<!-- tomcat-app-datasource.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/jpa-persistence-conf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/jdbc-persistence-conf.xml"/>

   <bean id="appDataSource"  p:username="username" p:password="password"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" p:url="url"/>

    <!--<bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" id="hikariConfig"
          p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
          p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:h2:mem:egspring;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;MVCC=TRUE"/>-->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
          depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
          init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction">
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="30000"/>
    </bean>

   <!-- <bean id="appDataSource"
          class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig"/>
    </bean>-->

    <bean parent="dataSource" id="defaultJDBCDataSource"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" primary="true"
          class="com.emirates.egsframework.persistence.datasources.DatasourceRouter"
          lazy-init="true">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="RODS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="RWDS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="XADS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityDatasource"
          class="com.emirates.egsframework.persistence.datasources.DatasourceRouter"
          lazy-init="true">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="RODS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="RWDS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="XADS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditDatasource"
          class="com.emirates.egsframework.persistence.datasources.DatasourceRouter"
          lazy-init="true">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="RODS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="RWDS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
                <entry key="XADS" value-ref="appDataSource"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          parent="abstractEntityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oracle_pu"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultEntityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          parent="abstractEntityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oracle_pu"/>
    </bean>

    <util:map id="entityMangerFactoryMap">
        <entry key="audit" value-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <entry key="securityService" value-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </util:map>

    <!-- <alias name="defaultEntityManagerFactory" alias="entityManagerFactory"/>-->

    <util:properties id="jpaProperties">
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
            com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
        </prop>
        <!--<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>-->
        <!--<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform</prop>-->
        <!--<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</prop>-->
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
    </util:properties>

</beans>
```

I get the following error randomly and continuously sometimes and works fine while saving other objects of same type :
 Exception occurred while saving the  as org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: It seams that you are trying to access your repository in a non-transactional context. Can you please share your code ?

Comment: @Transactional annotation  is used, and this exception does not occur every time.

Comment: can you please add the exception's stack trace ?

Comment: @NAIT the complete stack trace is added.

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when you are performing database transactions in non-transactional context. For methods that performs database transactions you use @Transactional annotation in spring. For details on transaction management you can refer to
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: @Transactional annotation  is used, and this exception does not occur every time.

Comment: If it does not occur every time then please identify and share the conditions under which this exception occur. Otherwise, it would be difficult to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your `Service` class? For Spring transactions to be created you need to access your class through the Spring Application Context there and then and not through e.g. creating a new instance (`new Service()` will not work) and neither will accessing an instance or this class through a variable (even if the variable had its value set by spring initially)